# SQL Query: Count Identical Records by a number of Columns, but where another column is Distinct

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to wrap my head around the best way to get this, and I never to get to my desired result.

I have a table, here's a simplified version of it, without useless items; please excuse the poor formatting:

Table ICDs

```
Pin |Direction | Type    | Specifics | Channel
1   | output    | digital | open/gnd  |   1   
2   | output   | digital | open/gnd  |   2   
3   | output   | digital | open/gnd  |   3   
4   | output   | digital | open/gnd  |   4   
5   | output   | power   | open/gnd  |   5   
6   | output   | power   | open/gnd  |   5   
7   | input    | digital |   gnd     |   null  
8   | input    | digital |   gnd     |   null  
9   | input    | digital |   gnd     |   null  
 10 | input    | digital |   gnd     |   null       
 11 | output   | digital |   open/28     |  6  
 12 | output   | digital |   open/28     |  7
```

I want to find out - to count - how many different types of signals I have available. This I did with the following query:

```
SELECT Direction, Type, Specifics, Channel, COUNT(*) AS CountOf
FROM ICDs
GROUP BY Direction, Type, Specifics, Channel
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

The result of the query is:

```
Direction | Type | Specifics | CountOf
output | digital | open/gnd | 4  
output | power | open/gnd | **2**  
input | digital | gnd | 4  
output | digital | open/28  | 2
```

The only issue with this result is that the power outputs use 2 pins (due to high power) for the same channel, so in fact the output power line should have a countOf 1, instead of 2.

```
output | power | open/gnd | **1**
```

I tried doing a subquery and extract all lines where Direction, Type, Specifics and Channel are GROUPed before doing the above query, but this messes with the count of my gnd inputs where there is no channel number attributed.

Any suggestion how to tweak it for the desired result? I think I ought to be able to remove the duplicate channel lines, but not those where channel = null and then do the count. I just can't grasp how to do it.

Please note: the table is much larger and the query more complicated, but this is where my problem lies. Also, the coding is done in C# VS2017 if it matters.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Whence is the information by which we would know that power outputs have two pins, and therefore the count should be 1, not 2?

Comment: So what is your desired result @Razvan

Comment: What about this input | digital | gnd | 4  ?? The last column is null for 4 records, do you wish to count this as only one or 4??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DENSE_RANK()` in a subquery

```
SELECT Direction,Type,Specifics,CountOf=MAX(CountOf)
FROM 
    (
    SELECT *
          ,CountOf = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Direction,[Type],Specifics ORDER BY isnull(Channel,pin))
    FROM Table1
    ) AS a
GROUP BY Direction,Type,Specifics
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d00e6/1)

Please pay attention to `isnull(Channel,pin)` it uses pin when channel is NULL.
It works for the sample data but may not work for your actual data, tweak it according to your actual data.
Hope it helps